# How do you get an attached PDF from an e-mail and save it, php

Tags: php, email, imap, attachment

I've been stuck on this for hours. But basically, I have an inbox that gets sent e-mails with some content that I want to take out, and an attached PDF. I figured out how to take all the HTML out that I want, but how do I save the attached PDF?

This is the cod I have so far:

public function read_emails(){
        // set user to check

```
    $strUser     = "email";
    $strPassword = "passwrd";
    $delete_emails=false;

    // open
    $hMail = imap_open ("{webmail.somethingsomething.com:143/notls}INBOX", "$strUser", "$strPassword") or die("can't connect: " . imap_last_error());
    // get headers
    $aHeaders = imap_headers( $hMail );
    // get message count
    $objMail = imap_mailboxmsginfo( $hMail );
    if($objMail != NULL)
    {           
        // process messages
        for( $idxMsg = 1; $idxMsg <= $objMail->Nmsgs; $idxMsg++  )
        {
            // get header info
            $objHeader = imap_headerinfo( $hMail, $idxMsg );

            // get from object array
            $aFrom = $objHeader->from;

            // process headers
            for( $idx = 0; $idx < count($aFrom); $idx++ )
            {
                // get object
                $objData = $aFrom[ $idx ];
                // get email from
                $strEmailFrom = $objData->mailbox . "@" . $objData->host;
                //Get the subject 
                $message_subject = $objHeader->subject;
                //Get the body of the message
                $fullBody = imap_fetchbody($hMail,$idxMsg, 2);//displays full body including junk
                $bodyMessage = quoted_printable_decode($fullBody);
                //Get the msg structure 
                $message_structure = imap_fetchstructure($hMail, $idx);
                //WHAT DO I DO HERE????
            }

            // delete message
            if($delete_emails == true){
                imap_delete( $hMail, $idxMsg );
            }

        }

        // expunge deleted messages
        if($delete_emails == true){
            imap_expunge( $hMail );
        }


        //Clears the cache
        imap_gc($hMail, IMAP_GC_ELT);

    }
    // close
    imap_close( $hMail );



}
```

I have the message structure, and if I print_r that I can see that there is an attachment in one of the parts, and I can see that it's a PDF. Not sure what comes next. I've tried and can't seem to find a good solution.

Thanks!

Edit: Here is the content of imap_fetchstructure

stdClass Object ( [type] => 1 [encoding] => 0 [ifsubtype] => 1 [subtype] => MIXED [ifdescription] => 0 [ifid] => 0 [ifdisposition] => 0 [ifdparameters] => 0 [ifparameters] => 1 [parameters] => Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [attribute] => boundary [value] => f46d044473ef81609f04d5f1997c ) ) [parts] => Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [type] => 1 [encoding] => 0 [ifsubtype] => 1 [subtype] => ALTERNATIVE [ifdescription] => 0 [ifid] => 0 [ifdisposition] => 0 [ifdparameters] => 0 [ifparameters] => 1 [parameters] => Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [attribute] => boundary [value] => f46d044473ef81609b04d5f1997a ) ) [parts] => Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [type] => 0 [encoding] => 0 [ifsubtype] => 1 [subtype] => PLAIN [ifdescription] => 0 [ifid] => 0 [lines] => 1 [bytes] => 37 [ifdisposition] => 0 [ifdparameters] => 0 [ifparameters] => 1 [parameters] => Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [attribute] => charset [value] => ISO-8859-1 ) ) ) [1] => stdClass Object ( [type] => 0 [encoding] => 0 [ifsubtype] => 1 [subtype] => HTML [ifdescription] => 0 [ifid] => 0 [lines] => 1 [bytes] => 37 [ifdisposition] => 0 [ifdparameters] => 0 [ifparameters] => 1 [parameters] => Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [attribute] => charset [value] => ISO-8859-1 ) ) ) ) ) [1] => stdClass Object ( [type] => 3 [encoding] => 3 [ifsubtype] => 1 [subtype] => PDF [ifdescription] => 0 [ifid] => 0 [bytes] => 179876 [ifdisposition] => 1 [disposition] => attachment [ifdparameters] => 1 [dparameters] => Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [attribute] => filename [value] => Statement of Account.pdf ) ) [ifparameters] => 1 [parameters] => Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [attribute] => name [value] => Statement of Account.pdf ) ) ) ) )

Answer (score 0):

According to the [doc](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imap-fetchstructure.php), you have an array of body parts in `$message_structure->parts`, so you could loop through this array and stop when the part's `->type` and `->subtype` correspond to PDF document. Something like:

```
foreach ($message_structure->parts as $idx => $part) {
    if (TYPEAPPLICATION === $part->type && 'pdf' === strtolower($part->subtype)) {
        $data = imap_fetchbody($hMail, $idxMsg, $idx);
        // Then you should check the $part->encoding
        // to decode data appropriately, e.g.:
        if (ENCBASE64 === $part->encoding) {
            $data = base64_decode($data);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: don't you have to download the pdf or something and save it? How do you do that

Comment: I immagine I would have to get the data and encode it somehow?

Comment: Hmm, ok... so I did that. and then I saved the file: write_file('static/statements/attachment.pdf', $data); (I'm using codeigniters file helper). There is a pdf file that gets written, but when I go to open it, it says: Adobe Reader could not open 'attachment.pdf' because it is either not a supported file type or because the file has been damaged (for example, it was sent as an email attachment and wasn't correctly decoded).

Comment: Does your saved file have the size equal to 179876 bytes?

Comment: The file actual attachment size is 1799680. The size of the file it's saving is 0 bytes

Comment: Could you update the code? Also try to print the size of the `$data` after fetch and after decode to see what's going on

Comment: Data before base64_decode gives me all the info in the e-mail. after decode gives me nothing